# Nomes trocados em uma coluna: como substituir valores em uma coluna mantendo o restante do `data.frame` constante?

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr

Importei uma planilha onde duas observações vieram trocadas e o restante foi corretamente preenchido.

Meu problema pode ser demonstrado com o exemplo abaixo: os valores atribuídos para o indivíduo `nome=="Foo"` são na realidade os valores do indivíduo `nome=="Bar"`. E vice-versa (os valores de `Bar` estão estocados na linha de `Foo`). Logo, pelo que entendi, eu precisaria somente reposicionar os nomes dos indivíduos de acordo com os valores corretos:

```
library(tidyverse)

nome <- c("Foo", "Bar", "FooBar",  "Baz")

set.seed(13)
df <- tibble(
  nome = rep(nome, 4),
  ano = rep(2015:2018, each=4),
  valor = sample(50, 16),
  valor2= sample(LETTERS, 16, replace = TRUE),
  valor3= sample(letters, 16, replace = TRUE)
) %>% arrange(nome)

print(df)
   # A tibble: 16 x 5
   nomes    ano valor valor2 valor3
   <chr>  <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> 
 1 Bar     2015    13 P      v     
 2 Baz     2015     5 R      c     
 3 Foo     2015    36 J      x     
 4 FooBar  2015    19 W      o     
 5 Bar     2016     1 O      b     
 6 Baz     2016    33 N      c     
 7 Foo     2016    45 D      l     
 8 FooBar  2016    26 R      t     
 9 Bar     2017     2 Q      f     
10 Baz     2017    35 L      p     
11 Foo     2017    37 C      p     
12 FooBar  2017    27 A      z     
13 Bar     2018    21 Q      x     
14 Baz     2018    49 K      i     
15 Foo     2018    34 I      q     
16 FooBar  2018    22 L      d  

# Como trocar SOMENTE `nomes=="Bar"` por `nomes=="Foo"` mantendo as demais colunas na mesma posição?
```

No exemplo acima eu poderia reescrever o vetor de `nomes`, mas gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira mais segura e prática de fazer isso. Alguma dica?

Comment: Você quer inverter estas duas categorias da variável `nome` simultaneamente?

Comment: Sim. Algo como `df$nome[df$nome=="Foo"] <- "Bar"` junto com `df$nome[df$nome=="Bar"] <- "Foo".
`

Comment: Veja se a minha resposta atende o que deseja.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recodificar simultaneamente os valores com a função `recode` do `dplyr`. Primeiro, vou criar um objeto `data`:

```
library(tidyverse)

nome <- c("Foo", "Bar", "FooBar",  "Baz")

data <- tibble(
  nome = rep(nome, 4),
  ano = rep(2015:2018, each=4),
  valor = sample(50, 16),
  valor2= sample(LETTERS, 16, replace = TRUE),
  valor3= sample(letters, 16, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(nome) %>% 
  print()
```

Agora a conversão simultânea:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(nome = recode(nome, Bar = 'Foo', Foo = 'Bar'))
```

Se preferir, crie uma nova variável ao invés de sobrepor a atual (`nome`):

```
data %>% 
  mutate(new = recode(nome, Bar = 'Foo', Foo = 'Bar'))
```

Nomeei uma nova variável `new`, deixando a anterior (`nome`) inalterada.

Comment: Era exatamente tipo de solução que eu buscava! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)